# How to write to the microphone input using Java?

Tags: java, microphone, javasound

I know this sounds strange, but is there any way to make the system think that the microphone is receiving input? I want to give the microphone my own audio as input, but i can't see a way to do it. Help?

Comment: *"I want to give the microphone my own audio as input,"*  Well the microphone it is 'voice controlled' so to ..speak. ;)  What is the end *user feature* you intend to offer by supplying sound to the microphone by programmatic means?

Comment: Not only it is not possible, but it also does not make sense: there is no circuit on the board to drive the coils inside the mic to produce sounds (there's no guarantee that there would be coils in there at all). This is roughly as "useful" as trying to read from a printer. If you plug the mic into the head phone jack, it *might* produce sound when you send your audio to the head phones. At the same time, it may break your mic and your main board, so don't try it at home ;-)

Comment: To inject data inbetween hardware and operating system on a modern machine generally requires rootkitting the computer, which is not a task for java or an activity that makes your users happy :)

Comment: What I'm trying to do is get the audio input from a line-in and mix it with the mic-in and send the combined data to another app, say Skype in this case.

Answer (score 1):

The first step is opening up your AudioSystem and inspecting the various channels/mixers and locating the relevant lines. Have you done this? The tutorial that covers this is here:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/sound/accessing.html

I just made an audio mixer, but it only mixes wav files and clips, down to a single output SourceDataLine. I haven't tried reading multiple mike inputs myself. But mixing is not that bad if you can open two TargetDataLines from the sources, read the same number of samples from each per buffer load, convert the bytes to values that can be added (possible scaling the volume of each so that they don't add up to more than the bit-encoding limit) then converting them back to PCM bytes.

Comment: I do have a way to get the TargetLines, and I think I know how to mix them, but how can I make Skype take that data?

Comment: I think, (not sure) that you just are going to have to look in Skype and see which audio line you have configured. I don't know that there is a way to tell that a line (from the Operating System point of view) ends up being used for this app or that. Maybe someone else knows.

Comment: I can use my Built-In line in or Mic, and that's it.